# Sampling on conditions within another column

Tags: r, random

How can I randomly sample 2 reports that have weights between 0.5 - 1.0

Also; How can I randomly sample 20% of reports that have weights between 0.5 - 1.0

```
DF <- data.frame(Report_ID=c(2,8,12,15,16, 51,67,89,88,98),
                        Weight=c(0.05,0.1,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.56,0.75,0.81,0.95,1.0))
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems pretty straightforward. Where are you getting hung up? And have you done any searching on SO or google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Sample 2 reports:

```
DF %>% 
  filter(between(Weight, 0.5, 1)) %>% 
  sample_n(2)
```

Sample 20% of reports:

```
DF %>% 
  filter(between(Weight, 0.5, 1)) %>% 
  sample_frac(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
rand_sample <- DF[ sample( which(DF$Weight > 0.4 & DF$Weight < 1.1), round(0.2*length(which(DF$Weight > 0.4 & DF$Weight < 1.1)))), ]
```